# How to make this label multi line?

Tags: vb.net

This is my problem

```
Me.lbl_questionEng.text = dt.Getstring(question_eng)
```

The Teacher informs you of your obtain score in Exa... 'it appears in a straight line

I want to like this

The teacher informs you of your score in examinations,quizzes, assignments,project and group work.

'question_eng comes from the mysql Database but its too long to handle by lbl_questionEng.text i need to make my label a multi line :/ but idunno . I see Environment.Newline but i dont know where to pu it

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
lbl_questionEng.AutoSize = False
```

using the label's property explorer. You may have to set its width and height manually or set dock to fill to make it large enough to hold all your text, but the text will wrap and fill the label's available space.

Comment: I found this so useful :) Thank you Sir :)